# Getting exception while running Angular application in my local

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I'm trying to run my Angular application in my local machine, But I'm getting below error.

[image]

This is my package.json file

```
{
  "name": "appauth-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "author": "KD, Angular",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/common": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/router": "~8.2.14",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@openid/appauth": "^1.2.6",
    "bootstrap": "^4.4.1",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.803.20",
    "@angular/cli": "~8.3.20",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "~8.2.14",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.3.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.4.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.15.0",
    "typescript": "~3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Note : I have deleted my node_modules folder and tried again, but getting same error.

Please help me to resolve this issue, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using an old version of Angular, while the library angular jwt support only the active one as they say in software documentation

```
Requirements
This project only supports the actively supported versions of Angular as stated in the Angular documentation. Whilst other versions might be compatible they are not actively supported
```

Answer (score 0):

Your library is not compatible with your version of Angular.

According to the [changelog](https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) for `@auth0/angular-jwt`, in version `5.0.0`:

> Note: This release drops support for Angular <12 as those versions are no longer supported by Google themselves.

Either downgrade your version of the library, or migrate to a newer version of Angular.